# Http to HttpClient (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, http, http-request, httpclient

Estou tentando atualizar as requisições `Http` para `HttpClient` em Angular. Atualmente o código é:

```
return this.http.get(`${this.url}/grupos`).map(res => res.json());
```

Depois de pesquisas estou tentando atualizar dessa forma (sem êxito):

```
return this.httpClient.get(`${this.url}/grupos`, { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}});
```

Tive alguns problemas com erros em `GET/Unauthorizing` que não consegui corrigir.

Comment: Para o acesso dessa api é necessário algum token?

Comment: Acredito que sim, porém na versão atual não é enviado nenhum token e funciona corretamente, na que quero complementar segui pela mesma lógica de não trabalhar com tokens. Acha que pode ser isso?

Answer (score 0):

O http client faz o parse pra json automatico então o código:

```
return this.http.get(`${this.url}/grupos`).map(res => res.json());
```

vira:

```
return this.httpClient.get(`${this.url}/grupos`);
```

Comment: Obrigado! Havia descoberto ontem que o problema era com o token mesmo, o http anterior era interceptado e adicionado o token, enquanto as novas requisições com httpClient não eram.